# Implementing IDocHostUIHandler interface for VC++ Web browser control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, webbrowser-control

I have a VC++ MFC dialog application with a web browser ActiveX control. What I ultimately want to achieve is disallow click action on the links in a web page loaded in the browser control. In other words, clicking on hyperlinks on the web page inside the web browser control should do nothing (no redirect to that new URL). After researching on this issue, I found on MSDN and stackoverflow (e.g. [MFC : How to capture a link click event in a web browser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294636/mfc-how-to-capture-a-link-click-event-in-a-web-browser-control) which talks not about the same thing, but a similar requirement of customizing the context menu) that the ideal way to do it would probably be to implement the IDocHostUIHandler interface and write my own custom code inside IDocHostUIHandler::TranslateUrl.

Now while I found quite a lot of code around, as a beginner in COM interfaces, I am unable to understand how I would actually go about introducing this part into my existing code. Do I copy-paste the interface codes into my source? Or are there any steps to auto generate this code for VC++?

Any help in terms of some step-by-step sample on how to go about it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way may be to process the `DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2` event, filter for allowed URLs and set the `Cancel` parameter to `TRUE` to stop the navigation.

See [Controlling Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Controlling_Navigation)

Comment: The MSDN link talks about "implementing your IDispatch::Invoke method to handle DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2". Would that be the same as handling the BeforeNavigate2 event in the dialog control in the same way as handling any other MFC dialog control events (using the dialog editor, selecting the event and auto-generating a function to handle it)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how that work with MFC. I added the MFC Tag. If the BeforeNavigate2 is present in the Dialog Editor, that should be fine. Try it :-)

Comment: I used the BeforeNavigate2 event of the web browser and set my navigation restriction there, it works as expected. Thanks for the pointer.